# Connecting Postgres Heroku with Knex not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

We're having difficulty setting up a Heroku/Postgres database with Knex running our queries. We've set up our heroku/postgres db and created our tables, but we're having difficulty connecting to it with Knex. To make matters worse, there's almost no documentation on connecting Heroku/Postgres with Knex or any ORM so trying to figure this stuff out has been a real pain.

These are the connection patterns that I've tried.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    user: username,
    password: password,
    host: host,
    port: port,
    database: database,
    ssl: true
  }
  }
});
```

And... Note the ssl true was toggle and removed all together to no avail.

```
  var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL,
    ssl: true
    }
  });
```

We've also tried this pattern as well:

```
var pg = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL
 });
```

We haven't yet pulled down a copy of our localdb, so every test we run is basically a git commit. We're basically testing an insert query on a GET request to our root (index.html) page. So on any get request to the main page, it should insert something into our waterrates table. If I switch it from insert to select, it returns an object but you can't actually see any of the data in the object.

The inserts we're attempting to use are:

```
knex.select('*').from('waterrates').then(function(rows){
  return rows;
});

knex('waterrates').insert({name: 'pleeeaseee work'}, {rate: 100}).then(function(rows){
   console.log(rows);
})

knex.select().
```

We're actually uncertain where the error could be as attempting to connect doesn't yield any errors. It's probably something silly, but we have no idea where/how to troubleshoot this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 5):

I had an old version of PG installed which was causing the issue. We changed our package.json file to use the latest PG. Heroku updated it and it worked!

As a side note, if anyone looks at this in the future, heroku requires an SSL connection. Keep that in mind when you're working. The connection string that I provided above should work for you all.

B

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is dealing with this problem.

Please set "SSL" to false if you don't use paid dynos.

Heroku only assigns "SSL" to users who use paid dynos.

```
const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    connectionString : process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: false
  }
});
```